# Where can I see the installed profiles in iOS9

Tags: iphone, ios, certificate

Where is `Settings > General > Profile` in iOS 9?

I was part of a testing-team for an iOS app and using testflight. Back then, under iOS 6, I had to install a profile on my iPhone. Now, years later, I am again helping out to test with testflight, and I am having problems with certificates. I just wanted to check which profiles are installed on my iPhone, however, the `Settings > General > Profile` menu is not here any more under iOS 9.

**How can I see the profiles that are installed?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't see a profile entry until the first one is saved. It's listed when it shows up immediately below the VPN entry, so be sure you scroll the content up so that VPN and below are visible.

Other than that, you can tap through each profile and see details about what entitlements it controls and how it's authenticated and/or cryptographically singed in the same manner as before.

Comment: After installing the certificate the menu was visible! Thank you!